# How to load different size image into memory and then use Dataset api to read it in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently, I want to improve reading data performance. i'm use TensorFlow's DataSet api read data from disk. I want to know whether have method that read image data from memory and how to load image into memory. My image size is different and need to preprocess.
Now, my code that read image from disk is as fellows:

```
# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def _parse_function(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
  return image_resized, label

# A vector of filenames.
filenames = tf.constant(["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...])

# `labels[i]` is the label for the image in `filenames[i].
labels = tf.constant([0, 37, ...])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

Comment: You just copy pasted the code from here : https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#decoding_image_data_and_resizing_it

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya， yeah, i copy the code from the tutorial above. My code is more complex than the above. But they all load data from the disk. This code can state my question.